# Is username and password required to store data for Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it required that I have a username/email and password in order to save data to Firebase? From all the documentation I have read, it looks like I need to createUserWithEmailAndPassword, and then only after that am I capable of saving information to the database. Is this true? If so, can I auto-generate a username in the background and use that as a session identifier so that I can store data against it?

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            createNewUser(task.getResult().getUser());
        }
        hideProgressDialog();
    }
)};


private void createNewUser(User userFromRegistration) {
    String username = "username";
    String email = userFromRegistration.getEmail();
    String userId = userFromRegistration.getUid();

    User user = new User(username, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

Comment: You can create a fake email and password in the background with some random string generator, but why not just ask the user for the info? You will a neater firebase console.

Comment: @H.Brooks what you are saying is true, but I did not want to create a registration. This app is not that indepth. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. a username and password are not required to store data on firebase BUT they are required by default. All you have to do is go to your firebase console in the rules tab and change the default settings to this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!